# How do I remove a PPA added via command-line?

Tags: updates, ppa, repository

I added a PPA for updating my kernel for ubuntu-12.04. Later, I found that the kernel doesnot exist on the link within PPA.

I used this command.
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa`

Now if I try `sudo apt-get update`, I get an error 404, because  http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources, does not exist.

Trouble is I am unable to do an update. Even not able to do `sudo ppa-purge ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa`

Suggest a solution.