# Fail to download repository information

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager, ppa

Why lately I've been getting this error when I try to update my computer?

Ubuntu 12.04

Kernel 3.5.2

Processor i386

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found,
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found,
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: See the instructions here for removing a ppa: http://askubuntu.com/q/173195/173209