# How do I completely uninstall TV Maxe ?

Tags: 12.04, ppa, tv

I use Ubuntu Precise Pangolin 12.04.

I installed TV Maxe using the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:venerix/blug 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tv-maxe
```

How do I completely uninstall TV Maxe ?

Thank you.

Comment: See the answers here http://askubuntu.com/questions/173195/how-do-i-remove-a-ppa-added-via-command-line

Answer (score 3):

**Using PPA-Purge**

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:venerix/blug 
sudo apt-get update
```

**Manual Uninstall**

Type the following in this order into your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

--> updates the apt-get database

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge tv-maxe
```

--> removes the package `tv-maxe` including config files

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

--> removes leftover packages that were installed as dependecies including config files

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:venerix/blug
```

--> removes the software repository from the software.sources list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

--> updates the apt-get database

With both methods there might still be some configuration files left in your home directory. In order to remove them you will have to head to your home directory, hit `Ctrl` + `H` to display hidden files and search for any entries related to `tv-maxe`.

**Edit**: As gertvdijk has pointed out, ppa-purge is the better option here because of the external PPA.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is 'purging' the PPA.

See "How to purge a PPA" in [this blog article](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/how-to-use-launchpad-ppa-add-remove.html) on how to do that. This is generic for reverting upgrades done via a PPA.

I recommend doing this over just removing the PPA and removing the packages you *think* you have installed from it (as per the first part of the answer of @MHC). Here's why:

> Purging a PPA means not only to disable the PPA, but also to downgrade
>   any packages you've upgraded from that PPA, to the version available
>   in the official Ubuntu repositories.

So, also upgraded dependencies will be reverted to use the 'official' ones again.