# How do I get Bibletime 2.91 running on 12.04?

Tags: dependencies

I would like to install the latest version of Bibletime (2.9.1) on my computer because the version in the official repositories (2.8.1) has a bug with the "Mag" feature. I had installed 2.9.1 on 12.04 32 bit through one of the following ppa's:

```
ppa:pkgcrosswire/ppa
ppa:pkgcrosswire/developer-testing
```

Now on an Ubuntu 12.04.1 64 bit, I'm getting a dependency issue. It seems that it depends on libsword8 but it should actually depend on libsword9 which is available in the repositories. See http://sword-dev.350566.n4.nabble.com/Ubuntu-12-04-td4577002.html

Can someone help me install this app please?

**EDIT**: apt-get install -f bibletime yields the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bibletime : Depends: libsword8 (>= 1.6.2+dfsg) but it is not installable
             Depends: bibletime-data (= 2.9.1-0ubuntu0~r70~precise1) but 2.9.1-1~ppa2~precise is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I requested backporting of Bibletime 2.9.1 to precise. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/precise-backports/+bug/1056320

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to install Bibletime 2.9.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.1 64 bit. This is how:

1. Added the following repository `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main`
    2. In a terminal I typed `sudo apt-get update`
2. Followed by `sudo apt-get install bibletime` ignoring the warning messages
3. I removed the two software sources not to contaminate my system with other 'updates'
4. `sudo apt-get update` for the second time to clean the package cache.

Comment: That repository is the entire Debian main repository! I wouldn't add it, it will all sorts of packages from Debian that will conflict with Ubuntu's packages.

Comment: I know. And that is why, in step 3 in my answer I removed the repo from the sources list. I ignored all the update notifications I got , installed the package I was interested in, then removed the repo and run the update again to remove the notifications. It worked.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just download the package from http://packages.debian.org ?

Comment: Maybe, but .deb package management is 'trickier' for me. It is not so evident, for me, how to remove whatever a .deb file installs. With a ppa you can always ppa-purge in case of problems. Furthermore many .deb files give incompatibility errors.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to find the library at:

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/libsword8/1.6.2+dfsg-1
```

Donwload the .deb file, and install using:

```
sudo dpkg --install libsword8_1.6.2+dfsg-1_i386.deb
```

Then install BibleTime using:

```
 sudo apt-get install bibletime
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Actually that could be fixed with `-f` . open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: See my edit above

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't need both ppas installed: you only want `ppa:pkgcrosswire/ppa` and **not** `ppa:pkgcrosswire/developer-testing` as well, as that is causing the problems you are experiencing. The latter ppa is trying to install `2.9.1-1~ppa2~precise` and the former is trying to install `2.9.1-0ubuntu0~r70~precise1`. The `sword` dependency issues are also related to the situation caused by the ppas.

So, please remove the ppas by following the instructions [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173195/how-do-i-remove-a-ppa-added-via-command-line), and then run the following to clean out the system:

```
sudo apt-get purge bibletime
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then add again just the `ppa:pkgcrosswire/ppa` with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pkgcrosswire/ppa
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` and you should be able to install the latest version of `bibletime`.

---

If these instructions are unsuccessful, I can show you how to **build** it from source, as that is what I did. It is much better to compile rather than adding Debian repositories like the accepted answer recommends.

Firstly, follow just my instructions above for *purging* and *removing* bibletime, its files, and also its ppas (if any exist), so we can have a fresh start. To get the dependencies necessary for the program and its compilation, run:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep bibletime
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall cmake
```

Download the source from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bibletime/) and check its md5 signature.
Then unpack the source and cd to the downloaded folder and run

```
sudo ./build-release.sh
```

**Note**: The above command will build and install the program, but, alternatively, you could `cd` to the bibletime folder and run

```
./build-release.sh
cd build
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=bibletime --provides=bibletime
```

(Don't worry if you get errors after the build has finished, as changing directory to build and then running `checkinstall` does work.)

[image]

Comment: My first attempt was to add the first ppa but got a lot of dependecy issues. Then I removed it and added the second one and got the libsword8 issue. I'm hesitant to build from source because, from the little I know, this requires installing a lot of packages to compile, etc and that would "clutter" my system.