# 13.04 no context menu after rabbitvcs install

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, context-menu, rabbitvcs

I was using rabbit in 12.04 LTS and then upgraded to 13.04 while rabbit menu was gone. So I went to the [install page](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/ubuntu) and followed the instructions:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus3`
4. restart computer, no context menu. So I continued:
5. `sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-gedit`
6. `sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-cli`

   - Log out
   - log in
   - open nautilus,
   - right click on random folder

but still no "Rabbit VCS" in the context menu. I am certainly doing something incorrectly. But cannot figure out what...

**EDIT**
Nautilus version is 3.6.3 and it si basically the default which comes with Ubuntu 13.04 - in Ubuntu it is called as "Files"

Contents of `.config/rabbitvcs/RabbitVCS.log` :

```
2013-06-18 10:02:45,462 ERROR   rabbitvcs.vcs.svn       The path '/home/janipav/workspace/MassFileSender' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rabbitvcs/vcs/svn/__init__.py", line 254, in statuses
    update=update)
ClientError: The path '/home/janipav/workspace/MassFileSender' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
2013-06-19 09:56:19,047 ERROR   rabbitvcs.vcs.svn       The path '/home/janipav/workspace/XmlChanger' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rabbitvcs/vcs/sv2013-06-18 10:02:45,462 ERROR   rabbitvcs.vcs.svn       The path '/home/janipav/workspace/MassFileSender' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rabbitvcs/vcs/svn/__init__.py", line 254, in statuses
    update=update)
ClientError: The path '/home/janipav/workspace/MassFileSender' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
2013-06-19 09:56:19,047 ERROR   rabbitvcs.vcs.svn       The path '/home/janipav/workspace/XmlChanger' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rabbitvcs/vcs/svn/__init__.py", line 254, in statuses
    update=update)
ClientError: The path '/home/janipav/workspace/XmlChanger' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
2013-06-19 09:56:19,047 ERROR   rabbitvcs.vcs.svn       The path '/home/janipav/workspace/XmlChanger' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rabbitvcs/vcs/svn/__init__.py", line 254, in statuses
    update=update)
ClientError: The path '/home/janipav/workspace/XmlChanger' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
2013-06-19 09:56:19,437 ERROR   rabbitvcs.vcs.svn       The path '/home/janipav/workspace/MassFileSender' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rabbitvcs/vcs/svn/__init__.py", line 254, in statuses
    update=update)
ClientError: The path '/home/janipav/workspace/MassFileSender' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
2013-06-19 09:56:19,437 ERROR   rabbitvcs.vcs.svn       The path '/home/janipav/workspace/MassFileSender' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rabbitvcs/vcs/svn/__init__.py", line 254, in statuses
    update=update)
ClientError: The path '/home/janipav/workspace/MassFileSender' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
n/__init__.py", line 254, in statuses
    update=update)
ClientError: The path '/home/janipav/workspace/XmlChanger' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
2013-06-19 09:56:19,047 ERROR   rabbitvcs.vcs.svn       The path '/home/janipav/workspace/XmlChanger' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rabbitvcs/vcs/svn/__init__.py", line 254, in statuses
    update=update)
ClientError: The path '/home/janipav/workspace/XmlChanger' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
2013-06-19 09:56:19,437 ERROR   rabbitvcs.vcs.svn       The path '/home/janipav/workspace/MassFileSender' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rabbitvcs/vcs/svn/__init__.py", line 254, in statuses
    update=update)
ClientError: The path '/home/janipav/workspace/MassFileSender' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
2013-06-19 09:56:19,437 ERROR   rabbitvcs.vcs.svn       The path '/home/janipav/workspace/MassFileSender' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rabbitvcs/vcs/svn/__init__.py", line 254, in statuses
    update=update)
ClientError: The path '/home/janipav/workspace/MassFileSender' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
```

Contents of `/usr/share/rabbitvcs/configspec.ini`

```
[general]
language = string(default="English")
enable_attributes = boolean(default=True)
enable_emblems = boolean(default=True)
enable_recursive = boolean(default=True)
show_debug = boolean(default=False)
show_unversioned_files = boolean(default=True)

[external]
diff_tool = string(default="/usr/bin/meld")
diff_tool_swap = boolean(default=False)

[cache]
number_repositories = integer(default=30)
number_messages = integer(default=30)

[logging]
type = option("None", "File", "Console", "Both", default="Both")
level = option("Debug", "Warning", "Info", "Error", "Critical", default="Error")
```

Comment: What is your nautilus version?

Comment: it is 3.6.3 - will add it also into question

Comment: Is the file `.config/rabbitvcs/RabbitVCS.log` empty and can you paste the contents of `/usr/share/rabbitvcs/configspec.ini`?

Comment: question updated. It tells me to update my subversion client ... ok. But how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can fix the missing context menu. I suggest removing the installed PPA version and the ppa ([How do I remove a PPA added via command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173195/how-do-i-remove-a-ppa-added-via-command-line)), reinstall the version from Ubuntu and follow the instructions I derived from the bug reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rabbitvcs/+bug/1093533.

You need to download the following file http://rabbitvcs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clients/nautilus-3.0/RabbitVCS.py

Copy it (using root/su/sudo) to:

`/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/RabbitVCS.py`

You may also need to create the following symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
```

You will need to restart your session (log out and back in again) to see the changes.

Comment: I am one of the unlucky ones. But I feel like this will be way to fix it. Still not resolved for me, but at least knowing that its known bug helps me to sleep :) Rewarding also bounty for good answer. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: No need to logout after applying the changes; `killall nautilus` does the trick.

Comment: Solution is not working for me in Ubuntu 12.04....Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems like you have `.svn` files belonging to your older version of rabbitvcs(probably 1.6). These need to be upgraded to 1.7, which is the version you have installed. To do this, execute the following on a terminal:

```
svn upgrade
```

You need to reboot for this to complete. To reboot: `sudo reboot`

Comment: I already tried that and I get this error:
janipav@janipav-energy:~$ svn upgrade
`svn: E155019: Can't upgrade '/home/janipav' as it is not a pre-1.7 working copy directory
svn: E000002: Can't open file '/home/janipav/.svn/entries': No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you reboot your system after this?

Comment: I did even turn off and on the computer ... I am mentally preparing myselves that I wil simply use just only the svn commands from terminal...